# how to play video in wpf using mediaElement

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

My gaming application is required to play countdown video like as 5..4..3..2..1..0..go. I have ".wmv" video clip. I tried below code

Xaml Code:

```
<MediaElement Canvas.Left="343" Canvas.Top="476" Height="277" Name="mediaElement1" Width="338" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="mediaElement1_MediaEnded" />
```

c#:

```
media-element.Source = new Uri(Startsound);
media-element.Play();
```

But It doesn't work. I set LoadingBehaviors as manual also.

Comment: What's the value of Start-sound at runtime?

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? Your C# will not even compile. So please provide correct code, especially tell us what Start-sound is exactly.

Comment: @goobering- its one string which contain path of video clip

Comment: @Clemens- I did not get any error. But still video doesn't play.

Comment: Did you check if the path is valid at runtime? As a note, @user-, with a trailing minus, won't notify anybody.

Comment: MediaElement fails silently if you pass it an invalid Uri and hit Play - you don't get any error messages in the user interface. I did a quick test with the code you posted (*please ensure that your code works before pasting it - yours includes several illegal names*), and there's nothing wrong with the method you've used. Pretty sure your path's wrong.

Comment: My path is string start-Sound=@"D:\LEENA NEW PROJECTS\Laser Game\28 April15\LaseGame_New\LaseGame_New\Sounds\countdown.wmv" ...Its kinda type of illegal name coz stackoverflow did not allow gramatical mistake..thats why I have to change it over here

Comment: I did not get any error msg for path from UI

Comment: Hye I come to get that , I check for media-element.hasvideo then it false.

Comment: you haven't provided enough details, its hard to help you. Try your video with the msdn sample and lets see if it works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried all but it didn't work :-(